# index giving rows of the matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix named song with a row for each word occurring in five songs lyrics and a column of counts for each song.
I would like to create an index giving which rows of the matrix correspond to a word in x

```
x = c("is", "the", "I", "you")
```

I did

```
song[is.element(song, x),]
```

but this gives me another matrix which the value is true.

Comment: Will you provide a small sample `song` matrix to make a more reproducible example problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
which(song[,1] %in% x)
```

Does this help?